# KSQL Table - Table Join not working as expected

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb, confluent-platform

I am trying to join two tables in KSQL. The idea is to create a persistent table on top of joined query. I am using a Full Outer Join.

**Source 1 :**
Kafka Topic -> KSQL Stream -> KSQL table

**Sample data in Table Order :**

```
Key,Product_Name,Product_category   
Product_1|Category_1|2018-08-25,Product_1,Category_1    
Product_2|Category_2|2018-08-25,Product_2,Category_2    
Product_3|Category_3|2018-08-25,Product_3,Category_3    
Product_4|Category_4|2018-08-25,Product_4,Category_4    
Product_5|Category_5|2018-08-25,Product_5,Category_5
```

**Source 2 :**
Kafka Topic -> KSQL Stream -> KSQL table

**Sample data in Table Product:**

```
Key,Product_Name,Product_category
Product_1|Category_1|2018-08-25,Product_1,Category_1    
Product_2|Category_2|2018-08-25,Product_2,Category_2    
Product_3|Category_3|2018-08-25,Product_3,Category_3    
Product_4|Category_4|2018-08-25,Product_4,Category_4    
Product_5|Category_5|2018-08-25,Product_5,Category_5
```

The data flow in source 1 is continuous where as in source 2 which is fixed set it is once per day.

Join Query :

```
Create Table Order_Joined_Product as 
  select 
    A.key as Order_Key,
    A.Product_Name as Order_Product,
    A.Product_Category as Order_category,
    B.key as Product_Key,
    B.Product_Name as Product,
    B.Product_Category as Product_category 
  from Order as A 
    FULL JOIN PRODUCT as B on A.Key=B.Key
```

Now, the issue is if I do a count on the joined table it , the Order_Key count keeps on increasing with time and Product_Key count keeps decreasing with time.

What I want to achieve is by end of day I want to see the count of Products which in source 1 and not in 2 and the count of Products for which are is source 2 and not in 1.

Comment: Try to edit your post using code tags.

Comment: Would need more info to comment. 
- What version of ksqlDB?
- What does the source data look like?  Provide examples please - including timestamps.
- Are their duplicates in it?  
- For the given example source input, what's the required output?
- What statements did you use to create the streams and tables?
- What do you mean by "Order_Key count keeps increasing and Product_Key decreasing"?   Please share the SQL you're using to get these counts.